# A non-clean ring $R$ with $R/Soc(R_R)$ Boolean

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am searching for a non-commutative ring $R$ with identity such that $R$ is not a clean ring and $R/Soc(R_R)$ is a Boolean ring. By a clean ring I mean a ring each of whose elements is a sum of a unit and an idempotent, and by Boolean ring I mean a ring each of whose elements is an idempotent. I have run into [this article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870701866374) Example 4, but, $R/Soc(R_R)$ is not Boolean, though $R$ is not clean.

Thanks for any help and suggestion!

Comment: [Crosspost](http://mathoverflow.net/q/260353/19965)